# Android Studio 2.2 beta3 after running also gradle sync required

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I have changed gradle and running the app gradle sync is happening. But still the sync now option is displayed. Which i want to again sync the app. Can you please resolve this

Answer (score 0):

No U don't need to do sync once again. if still build or sync problem continues use

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Comment: Nope im reporting dis as a bug in beta 3

Comment: ohh,... that's what problem with these like beta :(

Comment: yeah bro. so tat v report bugs to make it better